# How to correctly use GCP log exclusion filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have created a GCP sink and want to exclude a specific log from GCP log explorer. There is an option called GCP log exclusion filter within GCP sink. I tried using regex and seems that the query syntax is correct. However, It doesn't exclude that specific log. I really appreciate if anyone can help me resolve this issue.

Below is an example log that I want to exclude coming into GCP sink from GCP log explorer.

textPayload: "127.0.0.1 -  07/Mar/2023:14:35:50 +0000 "GET /synergiq-k8s-ready.php" 200"

Basically I want to exclude logs which has resource.type=k8s_container, and textPlayload contains GET,POST, 127.0.0.1 with either 200 or 302 code.

I tried using below query in the exclusion filter but it's not actually excluding the log

resource.type=k8s_container AND textPayload=~ ".*127.0.0.1.+ GET.+ (200|302)"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on what you're actually trying to exclude here. The sample string that you want to filter out is a specific GET. But in the next line, you are broader in your criteria, and then your sample regex is filtering out POSTs, not GETs.

I'm going to go with the broadest criterion:

```
resource.type=k8s_container AND textPayload=~".*127.0.0.1.*(200|302)"
```

Alternately,

```
resource.type=k8s_container AND textPayload=~"127.0.0.1" AND textPayload=~"(200|302)"
```

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#regular-expressions)

Comment: sorry for the confusion and I have corrected it. All I want is to exclude a log entry which has GET or POST along with 127.0.0.1 and 200 or 302 code in it.  I will try your suggestion and post my feedback about it